# Specific number of elements in loop are not selecting if data retrieving from json or XMLHttpRequest in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

Looking for selection of next few elements by onclick on "next" button and selection of previous few elements by onclick on "previous" button. This works if its static data like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40026278/how-to-select-next-specific-number-of-elements-in-loop-by-every-click-in-pure-ja). But its not working if the data is retrieving from external files like XMLHttpRequest, json etc I'm getting same error in debugger as " Uncaught ReferenceError: nextfun is not defined ". Any solution?

```js
var myArray = [ { "display": "link 1", "url": "http://www.link1.com" }, { "display": "link 2", "url": "http://www.link2.com" }, { "display": "link 3", "url": "http://www.link3.com" }, { "display": "link 4", "url": "http://www.link4.com" }, { "display": "link 5", "url": "http://www.link5.com" }, { "display": "link 6", "url": "http://www.link6.com" },{ "display": "link 7", "url": "http://www.link7.com" }, { "display": "link 8", "url": "http://www.link8.com" }, { "display": "link 9", "url": "http://www.link9.com" } ];

myFunction(myArray);

function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' +
        arr[i].display + '</a><br>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;

 var next = document.getElementById("next"),
    prev = document.getElementById("prev"),
    list = document.getElementById("list");

    var li = id01.getElementsByTagName("A");
    var currentIndex = 0, amount = 3, len = li.length;

    var selectItems = function() {
        for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
            li[i].style.background = (i >= currentIndex && i < currentIndex + amount) ?
                "red": "yellow";
        }
        prev.disabled = currentIndex - amount < 0;
        next.disabled = currentIndex + amount > len;
    };

    var prevfun = function() {
        currentIndex-=amount;
        selectItems();
    };
    var nextfun = function() {
        currentIndex+=amount;
        selectItems();
    };
    selectItems();   
}
```

```css
#id01{ width:300px; } a{ height:25px;line-height:23px; width:300px; padding:5px; text-decoration:none;float:right; }
```

```html
<div id="id01"></div>

<button id="prev" onclick="prevfun()">PREVIOUS 3</button>
<button id="next" onclick="nextfun()">NEXT 3</button>
```

Comment: `nextfun` is inside your `myFunction` function ie. in local scope that's why when you click its undefined and throwing the error , you need to remove the code for `nextfun` definition and paste it outside in global scope same goes for `prevfun` and `selectItems ` i guess

Comment: I have already tried that but that too didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It solved. The 'out' variable must be declared in global scope and the selectItems(), nextfun and prevfun must be outside the myFunction(arr)

```js
var myArray = [ { "display": "link 1", "url": "http://www.link1.com" }, { "display": "link 2", "url": "http://www.link2.com" }, { "display": "link 3", "url": "http://www.link3.com" }, { "display": "link 4", "url": "http://www.link4.com" }, { "display": "link 5", "url": "http://www.link5.com" }, { "display": "link 6", "url": "http://www.link6.com" },{ "display": "link 7", "url": "http://www.link7.com" }, { "display": "link 8", "url": "http://www.link8.com" }, { "display": "link 9", "url": "http://www.link9.com" },  { "display": "link 10", "url": "http://www.link10.com" },  { "display": "link 11", "url": "http://www.link11.com" } ];

myFunction(myArray);
var out;
function myFunction(arr) {
     out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' +
        arr[i].display + '</a><br>';
    }
     document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
   var next = document.getElementById("next"),
    prev = document.getElementById("prev"),
    list = document.getElementById("list");
    
    var li = document.getElementById("id01").getElementsByTagName("A");
    var currentIndex = 0, amount = 3, len = li.length;

    var selectItems = function() {
        for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
            li[i].style.background = (i >= currentIndex && i < currentIndex + amount) ?
                "red": "yellow";
        }
        prev.disabled = currentIndex - amount < 0;
        next.disabled = currentIndex + amount > len;
    };

    var prevfun = function() {
        currentIndex-=amount;
        selectItems();
    };
   
    var nextfun = function() {
        currentIndex+=amount;
        selectItems();
    };
    
    selectItems();
```

```css
  #id01{ width:300px; } a{ height:25px;line-height:23px; width:300px; padding:5px; text-decoration:none;float:right; }
```

```html
<div id="id01"></div>

<button id="prev" onclick="prevfun()">PREVIOUS 3</button>
<button id="next" onclick="nextfun()">NEXT 3</button>
```